# iPhone sqlite3_next_stmt() support

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I get an error message of un-finalized statement when attempting to close the database connection in ApplicationWillTerminate method.

In order to find the source of the error I want to use the SQLLite next statement.

But it seems this statement is not supported as per the header files in iPhone OS 2.2.  Am I missing something  ?

Is there an alternate way to identify the trouble causing un-finalized statement in SQLlite. While I seem to be finalizing but I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged the same issue, unfinalized statements preventing me from closing my SQLite database on iPhone. `sqlite3_next_stmt` didn't appear to do anything, but I managed to track down the unfinalized statements manually. My db code was based on the SQLite Books example from Apple, specifically with the lazily prepared statements. Since I was doing this for several different statements, I decided to wrap this part of the code in an auxillary method, looking something like this:

```
- (void)updateIntFieldStatement:(sqlite3_stmt *)update_field_statement WithCString:(char*)cString toValue:(int)value {
    if (update_field_statement == nil) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cString, -1, &update_field_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
}
```

I would then call this code like this:

```
[self updateIntFieldStatement:static_statement WithCString:"UPDATE myTable SET myField = ? WHERE pk = ?" toValue:transmitted];
```

The problem is, `static_statement` would never get changed, it just stayed nil, so it would get lazily prepared again and again, and my finalization code never got to it. The reason was this part: `&update_field_statement`. My statement was an `sqlite3_stmt *`, but `sqlite3_prepare_v2` takes an `sqlite3_stmt **`, a handle rather than a simple pointer. The sample code from Apple got the handle by taking the address of the pointer, but when I did this in my auxillary method, I got the local parameter handle, not a global handle.

C pointer scoping: 1, me: 0...

The solution was to change my auxillary method to take a handle:

```
- (void)updateIntFieldStatement:(sqlite3_stmt **)update_field_statement WithCString:(char*)cString toValue:(int)value {
    if (*update_field_statement == nil) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cString, -1, update_field_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
}
```

and then get the handle at a global scope:

```
[self updateIntFieldStatement:&static_statement WithCString:"UPDATE myTable SET myField = ? WHERE pk = ?" toValue:transmitted];
```

Now the the statement only gets prepared once, `static_statement` gets assigned correctly when this happens and then eventually finalized, so I can close the database. Hope this helps you or someone else out there!